# Pearson chi squared for correlated sample

Tags: distributions, mathematical-statistics, combining-p-values

I am looking into the STS statistical test for random sequence.
There are multiple statistical tests for a random bit sequence and each of them produces a p-value or multiple p-value.

After the test finished, I have dozens of p-values for multiple tests and each of them distributes *approximately* uniform over $[0,1]$.

I would like to incorporate all of them to a single p-value:

If I assume the p-values are independent, then I can compute the Pearson chi square  on the p-values (i.e. discretize the uniform value to some discrete intervals, e.g. $[\frac{i}{10}, \frac{i+1}{10}]$).

The problem is that I cannot assume the p-values are independent.

What I can do:

I can compute the correlation matrix between all the p-values, and maybe multiply by the squared inverse to whiten the correlation and then assume they are independent,

Other more rigorous suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several methods for doing this. Perhaps Cinar, O., & Viechtbauer, W. (2022). The poolr Package for Combining Independent and Dependent p Values. Journal of Statistical Software, 101(1), 1–42. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v101.i01 may help you even if you do not use R. Cinar's PhD thesis which he defended earlier this year (2022) at the University of Maastricht may help you if it is available on-line.

Comment: If I understand correctly, to deal with dependent variable it is assume that the joint (pairwise) statistic is known and that the joint distribution (after normilize the p-value) is also jointly normal, right?